# does the command `evm --debug --code OPCODES` still work?

Tags: evm, testing, opcode

I've been trying to run this command `evm --debug --code 600580600b6000396000f36005600401`, and some [associated permutations of it](https://github.com/CoinCulture/evm-tools/blob/master/analysis/guide.md), such as:

```
evm --debug --code 366020036101000a600035045b6001900380600c57 --input 0101
```

However, all I ever see as a result is the help menu, i.e.

[image]

Has this command been deprecated, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you forget the `run` command?

Comment: what do you mean? I've not forgotten it- because I never knew it. can you maybe- show me an example? **UPDATE** wait- I did try that, for this `evm run --debug --code 600580600b6000396000f36005600401` I get this error `Incorrect Usage: flag provided but not defined: -debug flag provided but not defined: -debug`

Comment: I've tried `evm --debug --code 366020036101000a600035045b6001900380600c57 --input 0101 run` with `evm version 1.6.7-stable-ab5646c5` and it works.

Comment: yeah- I tried with `run` in the front, you need to put `run` in the back! anyway- thanks for your help! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've gotta put `run` in the BACK!

Like this:

```
evm --debug --code 6000355b6001900380600357 --input 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005 run
```